# How do I model across a mirror modifier?

Tags: mirror

I am modeling on a set of windows right now, and they are **not** symmetrical along the X axis, where I need the mirror modifier to mirror the other half of the superstructure. This is what it looks like. The problem basically arises when I need to make the windows non-symmetrical across the mirror.

One possible way would probably be to apply the mirror, make the adjustments, then separate the windows from the main superstructure and finally joining them with the superstructure afterwards?[image: The model on the left is not mine. I use it as a reference only]

Comment: add another mirror modifier

Comment: If I would, should it be above, or below the original one?

Comment: play with the order up and down how it fit to the model

Comment: Simply by using the copy command on the modifier, I suppose I don't need to separate the windows geometry from the original mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Separate the geometry that will be non-symmetrical, and rename it.

1. Select the object (by right-clicking on it), then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the keyboard to enter Edit mode.
2. Then, select the geometry that you want to separate, and press <kbd>P</kbd> (hotkey for separating) and you are done!

Now you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to go back into Object mode and see the separated geometry.

You can also rename a mesh by selecting it in the Outliner edtior (the object list in the far up-right in the default window layout), double-click the object's name and type in the new name instead of the one with a ".001" at the end given to the object by default.